# Data-table drawing based on condition(Remove search,pagination,show entries on condition)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have been working on a problem for a while..Still I cant figure it out.

I have a data-table. Here is the code.

```
$('#tableListUser').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    'iDisplayLength': 10,
    oLanguage: {
        sSearch: ''
    }
});
```

Everything seems fine until i have a requirement.

**Here is what i want**

1. If the **row count < 10** --> *Pagination,Show Entries,Search* **has to be removed**
2. If the **row count > 10** --> *Pagination,Show Entries,Search* **should be shown**(This is what i have right now)

After reading a bit i understood there is a scope for **drawCallback()**.But i am a noob on data-table.Ss this even possible? Please advise...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#tableListUser').DataTable({
responsive: true,
bDestroy: true,
iDisplayLength: 10,
oLanguage: {
    sSearch: ''
},
fnDrawCallback: function( oSettings ) {
    if(oSettings.fnRecordsDisplay() < 10 &&!$('#tableListUser' + '_filter').find(":input").val()){  
      $('#tableListUser' + '_length').hide();        
      $('#tableListUser' + '_filter').hide();        
      $('#tableListUser' + '_paginate').hide();
    }
    else{   
      $('#tableListUser' + '_length').show();        
      $('#tableListUser' + '_filter').show();  
      $('#tableListUser' + '_paginate').show();  
    }

}
});
```

I built you a small fiddle for this:
https://jsfiddle.net/c1dgxq78/1

Comment: I made small change..please update it in the fiidele

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c1dgxq78/1/ ... but you know, you can create a free jsfiddle account yourself and simply FORK my fiddle for yourself? :)